# How to check if the signs of a Series conform to a given string of signs?

Tags: python, pandas, series

For example I have a Series as below,

```
ts = pd.Series([-1,-2.4,5,6,7, -4, -8])
```

I would like to know if there is pythonic way to check the signs of `ts` against a list of signs, such as,

```
sign = '++++---' # returns False
```

while

```
sign = '--+++--' # returns True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution requires some numpy functions, but since you are using pandas for your data series, this is probably not an issue for you.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

values = pd.Series([-1, -2.4, 5, 6, 7, -4, -8, 0])
sign_str = "--+++--0"

sign_map = {
    "+" : 1,
    "0" : 0,
    "-" : -1
}

expected_signs = list(map(sign_map.get, sign_str))
observed_signs = np.sign(values)
np.all(expected_signs == observed_signs)
```

Answer (score 1):

To check the whether the elements of the Series are positive you could create a Boolean Series like this:

```
>>> ts >= 0
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
5    False
6    False
dtype: bool
```

(I assume `0` is positive, but this technique could be adapted if you choose otherwise.)

To get `sign` into a similar Boolean series, you can need to interpret the strings '+' and '-' strings as Boolean values. For example:

```
>>> sign = '++++---'
>>> pd.Series(list(sign)).replace({'-': 0, '+': 1}).astype(bool)
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
6    False
dtype: bool
```

Now you can compare the two series and use `all`. In one line, the whole thing looks like this:

```
>>> all((ts >= 0) == pd.Series(list('++++---')).replace({'-': 0, '+': 1}).astype(bool))
False

>>> all((ts >= 0) == pd.Series(list('--+++--')).replace({'-': 0, '+': 1}).astype(bool))
True
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach that doesn't require any string replacement operations:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

ts = pd.Series([-2, -4, -6, 5, 7, 9])
expected_signs = '---+++'

target_signs = np.array(list(expected_signs)) == '+'
actual_signs = ts.values > 0
match = np.all(target_signs == actual_signs)
```